# C# ASP .NET static class constructor is called on every request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, static, global-variables

I need a static class with static methods and variables in ASP .NET for global access. But the lifetime of my static class is just for one request. The static constructor is called on every request:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    private static object _obj;

    static MyClass()
    {
        DoSomething();
    }

    private static void DoSomething()
    {

    }

    public static void DoSomething2()
    {

    }
}
```

If I call `DoSomething2` in an aspx page, the static constructor is called everytime, so `DoSomething` is called everytime before `DoSomething2` instead of just once for the whole application.

**Update**:

I do something like this:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    private static MyClass2 _obj;
    private static AppDomainSetup _setup;
    private static AppDomain _domain;

    static MyClass()
    {
        DoSomething();
    }

    private static void DoSomething()
    {
        // the AppDomainSetup is initialized here
        //....
        //
        _domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, _setup);
        _obj = (MyClass2)_domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(MyClass2).Assembly.FullName, typeof(MyClass2).FullName);
    }

    public static void DoSomething2()
    {
        _obj.Method1();
    }
}
```

So I want to use the object from `MyClass2`, but I want to instantiate it just once because of performance.

Comment: How you know, your constructor getting called every time?

Comment: If I debug the IIS and put the breakpoints at the constructor, I can see that everytime I call DoSomething2, the constructor is called first. If I do 2 or 3 requests one after the other, the constructor is called on every request. I understood the static classes in asp .net as global classes for the whole appdomain, so I thought the static constructor is called once.

Comment: I guess somehow dll are unloaded from App domain....have you created seperate app domain for the libraray which contains your static class?

Comment: can you explain little bit more how this static class is used in your aspx page??

Answer (score 0):

you can set a static flag , when its true don't need run constructor like this :

```
 public static class MyClass
{
    private static object _obj;
    private static bool flag;
    static MyClass()
    {

        if (!flag) {
            DoSomething();
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    private static void DoSomething()
    {

    }

    public static void DoSomething2()
    {

    }
}
```

I run your Code without My edited , It just once time runc Constructor for each calling methods.

Comment: The problem is the object _obj is always null even if I create a new instance in the static constructor. On every request, the obejct is null again, I think the whole static class is thrown away, but I dont know why.